# How is VXLAN related to SDN?

Tags: sdn

I am currently setting up a testing SDN environment, so I am familiar with the sdn concept (separating the Control Plane from the Data Plane of a Switch).
Within my research I was often reading about VXLAN when there was talking of SDN.
Now I am a bit confused, because I understand VXLAN as a Tunneling Protocol and I dont know how this would be related to my idea of SDN.

Another question I would like to ask is: Would it be possible to Connect a Switch over several non-sdn Networks to a existing SDN Topology/ SDN Controller with the VXLAN Technology?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should differenciate between SDN as a concept and VXLAN as a tunneling protocol.

The later used to tag packets and hence you can do some kind of seperation in layer-2. This technique helps with network slicing and have been used in flowvisor.

Forwarding traffic through non SDN network have been studied in many works. I suggest you to read the last one
Magneto: Unified Fine-grained Path Control in Legacy and OpenFlow Hybrid Networks

Good luck